# Altering a table via SQL Server Management Studio - get SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

Is there a way to get the ALTER statement run by the management studio when altering a table in the design view?

Comment: No, the SQL Server table has to be closed to alter it, and there is no way to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the generate change script button. It appears after making a change via the designer window.

[image]

This allowed me to run the changes on other hosts with a query rather than going through the GUI again.

Comment: Care to add more detail? (Where did you find it? What did it do? Maybe a screenshot? :-)

Comment: Added a screenshot. Thought maybe this was common knowledge

Comment: It might be, but only about half of us spend any significant amount of time in Windows - Knowing where it is/what the icon looks like saves us from having to dig through menus or mouse over every icon and wait for the tooltip when we need to use the feature :-)